# Prime number in EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i want to create a function prime(x) and x can be "B1", "A3" or another cells. However, I feel so stuck with my code in EXCEL VBA. Can anyone help me? Thank you so much.

```
Function prime(x As String) As Boolean


Dim i As Integer, y As Integer

y = Range("x")

For i = 1 To ROUNDOWN(Sqr(y, 0))

    If y Mod i = 0 Then

    prime = True

    Else

    prime = False

    End If

Next i

End function
```

Comment: `Function prime(x As Range) As Boolean` and `y = x.Value`

Comment: I have tried yours but still pop-up invalid property assignment

Comment: Use `B1` or `A3`. No quotes.

Comment: I feel you have the true/false reversed?  It should be prime if all the numbers result in a remainder?  I would set `prime = True` before the loop.  Then in the loop you would assign `False` if the remainder is 0.

Comment: Let me try, thank you both of you

Comment: And you want your loop to start at 2 not 1, 1 will always divide evenly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you want to use Range in the function not string.

Then you want to set the boolean as True and loop to see if it is divisible.

Then start the loop at 2

```
Function prime(x As Range) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, y As Long
    y = x.Value
    prime = True
    For i = 2 To Application.RoundDown(Math.Sqr(y), 0)
        If y Mod i = 0 Then
            prime = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```

---

Just an FYI, Office 365 Formula version:

```
=NOT(OR(MOD(A1,SEQUENCE(ROUNDDOWN(SQRT(A1),0)-1,,2))=0))
```

Older versions:

```
=NOT(OR(MOD(A1,ROW($ZZ2:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,ROUNDDOWN(SQRT(A1),0))))=0))
```

Comment: aw thank you, I got it 

Comment: Showing VBA plus different tabular versions is very instructive. - Side notes to the tricky formulae: a) MS365 formula fails with input numbers 1, 2 and 3 (`#CALC!`) trying to start a sequence by `0`, b) the older version doesn't see  2, 3 and 5 as primes due to similar effects including row confusion (`2:1`). @ScottCraner

Comment: Further side note to your compact & valid VBA code: inserting the following *condition** on top of function `If num Mod 2 = 0 Then` : `If num > 2 Then Exit Function` :  `End If` could not only exclude even numbers greater than 2 from loop, but above all *reduce* the number of potential loop tests by about **half** using odd numbers only by starting loop at `3` in steps of 2 via
    `For i = 3 To Application.RoundDown(Math.Sqr(num), 0) Step 2`
 @ScottCraner